# The law of large numbers when using the midrange estimator for expectation

Tags: estimators, law-of-large-numbers

I have a growing sequence $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \cdots$ of finite sets that contain samples of $X \sim U([a, b])$. From this sequence I construct a sequence of estimates of $\mathbb{E}[X]$ using the midrange estimator, for some $A_i$ it is $(x^{A_i}_{(1)} + x^{A_i}_{(n)}) / 2$.

How can I refer to the fact that the estimator sequence converges? If I was using arithmetic mean it would be the law of large numbers.

Comment: You can (easily) work out the distribution of each $A_i.$  No laws of large numbers are needed.

Comment: @whuber sorry what do you mean? in my notation above $A_i$'s are just sets of reals

ultimately I could prove this myself but it's very tangential to the paper I'm writing and I just want the shortest way to *refer* to the fact that these estimators converge (if I was using arithmetic mean, I would say "and this sequence converges due to the law of large numbers")

Comment: You refer to them as "samples:" that means more than "just sets of reals."  Indeed, if they are only arbitrary sets of real numbers, you cannot conclude anything about the sequence $A_i$ except that it must have an accumulation point in $[a,b]$ (because this interval is compact).

Comment: @whuber Sorry, I should've been more precise. They are sets of reals constructed by sampling $X \sim U([a, b])$. All of this refers to a computer program that maintains a collection of samples, and iteratively adds new ones to it, therefore the sequence of sets grows. I hope it's not ambiguous anymore?

Comment: Assuming they are independent random samples, my first comment applies.  Otherwise, we need to know more about how you sampled.